# Laravel API Auth class usage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to build and API based on laravel that aims to grow to intense usage by lots of clients. My question is whether there are serious drawbacks of using `Auth` class in my code ?
I have implemented the OAuth2 authorization, and to get info about the user that is making the request I have a filter :

```
Route::filter('hasAccess', function($request)
{
        //get the cleaned token string
        $auth_code = Request::header('Authorization');
        $auth_code = trim(preg_replace('/Bearer/sui', "", $auth_code));
        //get the stored session and put the query in cache for 10 minutes
        $ts = DB::table('sessions as s')
                ->leftJoin('oauth_session_access_tokens as osat', 's.token', '=', 'osat.id')
                ->select('s.*')
                ->where('osat.access_token', '=', $auth_code)
                ->remember(10, $auth_code)
                ->first();
        //Auth user cross-app
        Auth::onceUsingId($ts->user);
        //Extract the requested action
        $request = $request->getAction();
        $request = $request['controller'];
        $parts = explode('@', $request);
        $required = strtolower($parts[0]).'.'.$parts[1];
        $required = preg_replace('/controller/sui', "", $required);
        //Get the permissions
        $permissions = json_decode($ts->permissions, true);
        $permissions = array_fetch($permissions,'name');
        if (!in_array($required,$permissions))
        {
            return Response::json([
                    'error' => true,
                    'dataset' => 'You don\'t have rights to access this url'
            ]);
        }



});
```

It validates the user access rights to the controller action, but the most interesting in it is the row with `Auth::onceUsingId($ts->user);`. This rows authorizez the user for only 1 request. Also if any other ways to get info about user exist, please mention them. Thanks

Comment: What are you asking? If you have to authenticate your user every request?

Comment: Not quite. I want to know if there is a serious perfomance or any other drawback, when the service will be consumed by lots of client.. for example 10k,20k.. etc.. So I want to be aware of the possible issues I can have. Also I want to know if it is a good way to get the user that makes request anywhere in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You talk about 'serious drawbacks' of using Auth class code - but you dont really explain drawbacks compared to what? Just manually looking in the database yourself for the user?

All the `Auth::onceUsingId()` is doing is logging your user into the application without a session or cookie. This is perfect for an API - as you dont normally have persistence between requests.

You can then do `Auth::user()` to get data about the user, such as `Auth::user()->name`.

Comment: I meant performance issues and any other not related to the beauty of the code. But, your answer seems to ecourage me that this approuch is ok. Thanks.